# Updating Stock Qunatity based on Orders using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble creating a SQL statement that will update the Inventory table everytime I add an order to the Orders table using a button.

Order Table

| id | orderid | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J1 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 10 | 120 |
| 2 | J2 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 5 | 100 |
| 3 | J3 | Duck | 1.6 | 2 | 250 |
| 4 | J4 | Turkey | 1.6 | 4 | 350 |

Inventory Table

| id | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 20 | 120 |
| 12 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 15 | 100 |
| 13 | Duck | 1.6 | 5 | 250 |
| 14 | Turkey | 1.6 | 9 | 350 |
| 15 | Native Chicken | 1.9 | 20 | 120 |
| 16 | Chicken Broiler | 2.5 | 15 | 100 |
| 17 | Duck | 1.7 | 5 | 250 |
| 18 | Turkey | 4.7 | 9 | 350 |

Expected Result

| id | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 10 | 120 |
| 12 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 10 | 100 |
| 13 | Duck | 1.6 | 3 | 250 |
| 14 | Turkey | 1.6 | 5 | 350 |
| 15 | Native Chicken | 1.9 | 20 | 120 |
| 16 | Chicken Broiler | 2.5 | 15 | 100 |
| 17 | Duck | 1.7 | 5 | 250 |
| 18 | Turkey | 4.7 | 9 | 350 |

this is the code that I'm trying to use using a query in visual studio and every time I run it the quantity keeps on decreasing.

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET Quantity = TableA.Quantity - TableB.Quantity

FROM Inventory AS TableA JOIN tblOrders AS TableB ON TableA.Variety = TableB.Variety

WHERE
TableA.Variety = TableB.Variety
AND
TableB.Weight = TableB.Weight
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh, I'm using SQL Server for this one.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can use:

```
update inventory
    set quantity = quantity -
                   (select sum(o.quantity)
                    from orders o
                    where o.variety = inventory.quality and
                          o.weight = inventory.weight
                   )
    where exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.variety = inventory.quality and
                        o.weight = inventory.weight
                 );
```

Many databases have more concise ways to express this logic.  But your question has not specified a specific database.

In SQL Server for instance, you can use:

```
update i
    set quantity = i.quantity - o.quantity
    from inventory i join
         (select o.variety, o.weight, sum(quantity) as quantity
          from orders o
          group by o.variety, o.weight
         ) o
         on o.variety = inventory.quality and
            o.weight = inventory.weight
```

Comment: I get this error The multi-part identifier "tblOrders.Variety",  "tblOrders.Weight", "Inventory.Quantity", "Inventory.Weight" could not be bound. `

Comment: @alexatorrento . . . You need to put the actual table names into the query.  The identifiers in this answer are based on **your question**.

Comment: i did put the table names but that's the error that I get :(